# Can't bind on form submit event

Tags: jquery

I'm using IE9.
jQuery.fn.jquery says `1.8.2`.

Code I'm using to bind on form submit:

```
$("#formName")[0].submit(function foo () {
    alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );       
});
```

Every time this code executes instead of binding, my `formName` form submits. How can I bind instead of submit?

Comment: Remove the `[0]`. You want to call `submit()` on the jQuery object, not the DOM object, and since you're using an id, there should only be one matching element anyway.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) does the trick (as mentioned by @Jason P)

```
$("#formName").on("submit", function(event)
{
    console.log("Handler for .submit() called.");
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the event from processing the submit request.
    console.log("Default submit event prevented from occurring.");
});
```

Note:

- using `.on()` ensures that your listener will notice changes in your DOM-tree.
- Your function does not need to be named when using event listeners.
- `[0]` is not required (as mentioned by @Robert Rozas), simply knowing the id is sufficient.
- Passing the event as an argument into the function allows you to work with it, i.e. the `event.preventDefault` part in this case.
- Using `console.log()` is recommended for temporary logging, use your awesome developer tools :)

Comment: After checking out some of the things PeterKA mentioned, I managed to solve it using `.on()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

@Jonast92's great answer should help you **bind** a handler to your form's `submit` event. I just thought that it might be important to point out a case where you might actually need the `[0]` your have in your code.

Let's say you've prevented the form from submitting and you've determined that the data is good enough and it's time to submit the form. You could use either **ajax** or **default form submission** to submit the form:

```
//ajax form submission
$.ajax( this.action,
        {data: $(this).serialize(), ...
        ........
});

//or default form submission
this.submit();
//or $(this)[0].submit();
//or $("#formName")[0].submit();
```

***POINTS TO REMEMBER***

- **`$('.form').submit()`** triggers `.form`'s `submit` event. This will cause any handler(s) bound to this event to fire. This will also cause the form `.form` to submit unless one of the handlers have `return false` or `event.preventDefault()`.
- **`$('.form').on('submit', handler)`** or **`$('.form').submit( handler )`** binds a handler `handler` to `.form`'s submit event.
- **`$('.form')[0].submit()`** causes the form to be submitted via default form submission. Please note that this does not trigger `.form`'s submit event and can therefore not be prevented via `return false` or `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: `$('.form')[0].submit() causes the form to be submitted via default form submission` - this did the trick. My form was being submitted using default form submission. I changed it to `$('.form').submit()` and it works. Thank you.